# S#arp Architecture NHibernate instead of Fluent NHibernate

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, s#arp-architecture

Is it possible to use NHibernate XML mapping files instead of Fluent NHibernate in S#arp Architecture framework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can. Take a look at the [Northwind sample app's NHibernate.config](http://sharp-architecture.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/src/NorthwindSample/app/Northwind.Web/NHibernate.config) (the commented `mapping` element and the related comments)

Comment: I had to comment out the following lines:
new AutoPersistenceModelGenerator().Generate()
in InitializeNHibernateSession() in file Global.asax.cs